# `position: fixed` doesn't work on Mobile Safari if an element's width exceeds device's height

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari, css-position

`position: fixed` is a quirky little fellow especially when it comes to mobile.

When attempting to use a fixed element with another element that has a width greater than the device's height, it breaks Mobile Safari.

I would like to keep the header on top while the content is scrollable. Is there a way around this issue without losing the experience?

Thanks in advance!

EXAMPLE:

http://debug.studiotate.com/mobile-safari-position-fixed (this is the issue i'm seeing - the header goes away when you scroll down and/or right)

EXPECTED:

http://debug.studiotate.com/mobile-safari-position-fixed/expected (this is what it should look like - the header stays put)

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }

    header {
      background-color: #00FF00;
      left: 0px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
    }

    div {
      background-color: #FF0000;
      height: 1500px;
      width: 1000px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185596/position-fixed-dont-work-on-some-mobile-device

Answer (score 0):

I think that div must be remove and set background to body

```
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

header {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry - failed to mention the the DIV will have various content (buttons, links, etc.)

Comment: Ok, let div in your code but put background-color to body.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The background-color is used to illustrate the issue and keep the code simple. The issue occurs whether or not the DIV has a background-color.